# HTML 5 multiplayer game with java server logic code duplication?

Tags: java, multiplayer, html5

I want to make a browser multiplayer game with java server.
I'm still in the design stage and i'm deciding what technologies to use.
But i stumble upon the problem when the client need the same logic as the server to predict movement and events before the response from server is received.
And i don't want a code duplication javascript and java.

So what are my options ?

Comment: Pretty much nothing, the client code can be much simpler than the server code to (interpolation between two values or even extrapolation is pretty easy)

Comment: Is there a reason you're locked into java as your server-side tech? You could share one common javascript codebase using a node.js server, if avoiding duplication and mismatches is a priority. Beyond that, have you looked into transpilers?